# How to change $0 to be mutable?

Tags: swift, immutability, mutability

I would like to replace specific element in array with another element like this:

```
let replace = ["123","87","123","765","som","123","op","123"].map {$0 == "123" ? $0 = "replace" : $0}
```

but I cannot do this because compiler throws me error:

```
error: cannot assign to value: '$0' is immutable
```

So, Is this possible to change $0 to be mutable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `$0` to be mutable. `map` will use whatever value you return, so you can use the last map like this:

`.map { $0 == "123" ? "replace" : $0 }`

When that `map` closure is run, whenever `$0` matches `"123"`, it will return `replace`, otherwise it will return the current value.

Answer (score -1):

This closure parameter in `map` function is immutable and can not be changed, as it is passed by value and gets copied from original value. Changing parameter's value is possible, if it is marked by `inout`, which is not your case here.